# Passing data from one controller to another through a route Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, routes

I have setup a system that relies on the routes.php and I have now come across a problem which is that I need to pass a variable to a route which redirects to a controller and receive that variable in the controller. Is this possible. Thanks

```
Main Controller
return redirect()->route('ROUTENAME')->with("Variable", Array);// Variable has to come from here

web.php
Route::get('ROUTE', "FUNCTION")->name('ROUTENAME');//Need to receive the array here and pass it on

RecieveFunction
$Variable;//This was passed from Main Controller and forwarded from the route
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use session()->get('Variable'); in the RecieveFunction

Answer (score 0):

You could do this to receive data:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::get('ROUTE', static function(Request $request){
    ...

    $variable = $request->session()->get('Variable'));
    # Delete the data if you don't to keep it in session
    $request->session()->forget('Variable');

    ...
} )->name('ROUTENAME');
```

OR if you want to pass it to Controller

```
use App\Http\Controllers\ReceivingController;

Route::get('ROUTE', [ReceivingController::class, 'function_name'] )->name('ROUTENAME');


# ReceivingController
public function function_name(Request $request)
{
    ...

    $variable = $request->session()->get('Variable'));
    # Delete the data if you don't to keep it in session
    $request->session()->forget('Variable');

    ...
}
```